# Find all points where a function is differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find all points where the function $f(z) = 2x − 3iy$ is
>   differentiable.

I found the partial derivatives: $u_x=2$, $u_v=0$, $v_x=0$, and $v_y=-3$ and they do not satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Does this mean that $f(z)$ is not differentiable at any point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is deffirentiable as a two real variables function everywhere since it is a polynomial. The fact that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are not verified anywhere means that the function is not holmorphic anywhere. Indeed $f$ is holomorphic in $z_0$ if $f$ seen as a two real variables function is differentiable in $z_0$ **AND** the Cauchy-Riemann equations are verified in $z_0$.

Comment: What is its derivative then?

Comment: @DHMO As a two varibales function its differential is $2dx-3idy$ but it does not have a derivative in the holomorphic sense since $f$ is not holomorphic

Comment: @Jennifer So the function is differentiable as a real function, but not as a complex function?

Comment: @sucksatmath Yes it is differentable as a two real variables function but not as a complex function